# underlining <p> on hover, but it shouldn't, using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an referal tag attached to a button so as to link the button to another page. I think its making the normal text is tags p and h2 to underline on hover. I've tried putting them in separate divs but it didn't work, any advice. Thanks in advance. Here's my current code:

http://imageshack.com/a/img923/3453/OAiDzL.jpg

Comment: Can you please post the relevant CSS code, or maybe even a fiddle to reproduce the problem?

Comment: You didn't include any code. We need to see the HTML and CSS that reproduces the issue.

Comment: `<a><button>..</button></a>` is not (technically) valid. Use CSS to make it look like a button if that's what you want.

Comment: Please include the code in the body of the question. Not an image. If we want to try and replicate the problem we are not going to attempt to re-type your code from and image. Also image shack is often firewalled in corporate environments

Answer (score 0):

As someone said putting button inside `<a href="#"></a>` is not valid. Instead make a class and style it with css. This approach should not interfere with your `<p>` and `<h1>` tag.

https://jsfiddle.net/10zbre2y/1/

```
<div class="col-md-7">
 <h2>Heading</h2>
  <p>text</p>
  <a href="#" class="btn" role="button">Hello World!</a>
</div>


.btn {
    -moz-border-radius: 28px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 28px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: solid #2A3A3F 2px;
    border-radius: 28px;
    color: #2A3A3F;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px 45px 10px 45px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
    background: #2A3A3F;
    color: #fccf29;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt but that still hasn't solved the problem

Comment: @JoeWild can you please post your html and css code and maybe on fiddle so we can see the problem you are experience.